# a probabilistic series limit?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits

Could anyone tell me $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}x(j)=?$ If I am given that $x(j)=1$ with probability $p$ and $x(j)=0$ with probability $q$, $p+q=1$

Thanks for helping.

Comment: do you know something about independence?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean by that? do you mean $p+q=1$? Yes this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find the limit in general but if $x(j)$'s are indepedent then  SLLN can be applied. The limit is the mean value of $x(1)$ which is $p$.

Comment: Thank you Kavi Rama Murthy.